Short sketch about spending time with "Friends"
I remember what I think was an episode of Mad TV with a short sketch in which a character (who I'm pretty sure was played by Phil LaMarr, but I could be mistaken) is talking to friends on the phone. His friends are trying to convince him to go out with them, but he declines, saying he's going to spend time with Friends. After the phone conversation ends, he turns on his TV, at which point an episode of Friends is just starting. He settles in happily, clapping along with the intro theme music.
All I can find is an episode where Mad TV spoofed Friends, which isn't what I'm looking for. Can anyone tell me where this sketch is from?

I was discussing this with a MADtv fan yesterday. He couldn't figure it out either, and he got so curious about it that today he tweeted Phil LaMarr... who replied!

@phillamarr here's a long shot- remember a bit where you won't go out cause you have plans with 'friends'. Hilarious I know it was you— Naked Crusaders (@nakedcrusaders) March 24, 2016

 

@nakedcrusaders Mad TV season two, I think "Imaginary 'Friends'" good sketch— phillamarr (@phillamarr) March 24, 2016
The synopsis on Planet MADtv describes the sketch:

An extremely lonely man.... thinks [the Friends characters] are in the room with him... When 8:00 comes around, he tells the women to go into the other room, as he will be with them in a half hour. After Friends.

I found someone who has Season One (not two), played episode seven, and watched "Imaginary Friends." It is indeed the sketch I had in mind. Mystery solved!
